# Error while trying upload a file with kendo-upload and Angular 5

Tags: angular5, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-upload

I'm trying to upload a file (image) to a remote server with Upload Component of Kendo UI for Angular.

**avatar.component.html**

```
<kendo-upload
        [saveUrl]="uploadSaveUrl"
></kendo-upload>
```

**avatar.component.ts**

```
uploadSaveUrl = 'http://localhost:9001/common/file/saveAvatar';
```

**error from browser console**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (upload.service.js:151)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (Subscriber.js:249)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:189)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:151)
at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:25)
at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)
at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    View_UploadComponent_0 @ UploadComponent.html:54
    proxyClass @ compiler.js:14645
    DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:14981
    ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1501
    dispatchEvent @ core.js:9948
    (anonymous) @ core.js:10569
    (anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:2628
    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
    onInvokeTask @ core.js:4724
    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
    Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
    ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
    invokeTask @ zone.js:1517
    globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1543

ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 14, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
    View_UploadComponent_0  @   UploadComponent.html:54
    proxyClass  @   compiler.js:14645
    DebugContext_.logError  @   core.js:14981
    ErrorHandler.handleError    @   core.js:1506
    dispatchEvent   @   core.js:9948
    (anonymous) @   core.js:10569
    (anonymous) @   platform-browser.js:2628
    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:421
    onInvokeTask    @   core.js:4724
    ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @   zone.js:420
    Zone.runTask    @   zone.js:188
    ZoneTask.invokeTask @   zone.js:496
    invokeTask  @   zone.js:1517
    globalZoneAwareCallback @   zone.js:1543
```

**Further information**

- the upload component is displayed correctly and I can choose a file
- all dependencies are up to date (I did: `npm update`)
- `UploadModule` is imported by my `shared.module`
- `HttpClient` is imported by `app.module`
- following request is started but nothing happens without the error above:

  ```
  Request URL:http://localhost:9001/common/file/saveAvatar
  Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
  Provisional headers are shown
  Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
  Origin:http://localhost:4203
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
  ```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.2",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.4",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^2.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^1.4.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^1.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^1.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^1.0.5",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^1.6.5",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^1.4.2",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^1.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.0.5",
"@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^2.1.0",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.1.2",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.4.0",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.46.0",
"angular2-moment": "^1.7.1",
"angular2-toaster": "^4.0.1",
"angular2-tooltips": "^1.0.10",
"cldr-data": "^32.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"ng2-redux": "^5.1.2",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"rxjs": "^5.5.2",
"tassign": "^1.0.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.20"
},
```

Please ask for more needed information. I don't know what else to write.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question: The error was in my HTTP interceptor. You have to handle the save request like:

```
    ...
    if (req.url === `${backendUrl}/file/saveFile`) {
        headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart form-data');

        return next
            .handle(req)
            .catch((error) => {
                return this.handleError(error);
            });
    }
    ...
```

Comment: can you please post you http intercepter solution?
 And did this saveurl work for you(for me it is giving 404 error):
uploadSaveUrl = 'http://localhost:9001/common/file/saveAvatar';